# Will chrome dev tool update in my code editor?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, html-helper

If I change something in dev tool on chrome, will it save and update vscode or do I need to copy/paste it over to the editor? I just started learning code this week please be nice.

Comment: "edge" browser has this functionality. only in the "vscode" editor. because "edge" and "visual studio code" are made by Microsoft. every change will be putted inside in the editor. but you need to activate that functionality first

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivMdw.png

Comment: No, it won't. This isn't normally how CSS is developed. I would suggest using something like [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

Comment: Chrome devtools can do it for CSS/JS if you add your [workspace folder](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, Firefox,... you've to copy and paste it. In edge is a function to auto-jump to the code line in vscode. But there is no save-function.